# Access a form control value from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <input ref="name" type="text" />
  ...
  <select ref="pet">
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

In another place, I have a different form, with different inputs, but the same `select`. I could simply bindly copy the code from the first one, but I don't want to.

I want to make a component. In terms of UI, I know it would work. However, I have no idea how to access `this.refs.pet.value` in that case:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <input ref="name" type="text" />
  ...
  <PetsSelect ??????? />
</form>
```

How to access the value of the `select` box from the component, in its parent (form)?

Comment: its erm. right up there in their examples. also, new ref api. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html - but your component for pets selection contains a form so you nested forms, that's a no go. you can mount the pets component into a ref and work with a value getter and compose - it's not hard

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I took a quick look on that page, but didn't understand how to solve my case... :(

Comment: The best way is to create method into parent component and pass it to child component as props, and whenever user changes the child component, it fires parent component method `onChange={(e)=> this.props.parentMethod(e)}` and maintain the state at parent component..

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha I thought of that, but I don't like that solution... I saw it in other React apps, but it doesn't feel natural to me, in this case.

Comment: Check this links [when to use props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and [lifting state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very quick example on composing

```
class PetsSelect extends React.Component {

  get value(){
    return this.state.value
  }

  handleChange(key, value){
    this.setState({[key]: value})
    this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(key, value)
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: props.value || '', name: '' }
  }

  render(){
    // add the name etc and then you can handleChange('name', ...) 
    // or make it more DRY
    return <div>
      <select 
        ref={select => this.select = select} 
        value={this.state.value} 
        onChange={e => this.handleChange('value', e.target.value)}>
        <option value=''>Please select</option>
        <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
        <option value='cat'>Cat</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  }
}


class Form extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.pets.value)
  }
  render(){
    // this.pets becomes the instance of the PetsSelect class.
    return <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
      <PetsSelect ref={pets => this.pets = pets} />
      <button type='submit'>try it</button>
    </form>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WExepp?editors=1010#0. basically, you can either: onChange and get the value in the parent, or read the value of the child when needed.

keep in mind you said 'controlled' - i am not doing anything to keep `props.value` with `state.value` - and in uncontrolled, you'd use `defaultValue`

Comment: Cool! I tried to simplify it a little bit, based on what you did: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdzBMR?editors=0010 Sorry if I'm missing anything, but isn't it better to have a `ref="pets"` in the child component and return its value in the `value` getter and use a strict (instead of callback) in the parent? It seems to work.

Comment: it works but it was deprecated about 2 years ago and it may be gone in 16 entirely. if you only care about the value, you can use that directly ->`ref={PetInstance => this.pet = PetInstance.value}`

Comment: What was deprecated? `<CustomElement ref="aStringHere" />`? Good to know, yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add ref like this `<PetsSelect ref="petSelect"/>` and get value by this `this.refs.petSelect.refs.pet.value` .

Comment: `this.refs.petSelect.refs.pet.value` — the `pet` here is redundant. Isn't it possible to expose the value directly as `this.refs.petSelect.value`?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2917 - `this.refs.foo` API has been deprecated for 2 years. as for OP's comment, you have not posted the component for pet select but it's quite trivial to expose whatever you like

Comment: You can't do that if tou put "select pet" in other component

Comment: @IonicăBizău If you want to access it as `value`, you can write a getter within the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FormComponent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {selected: null,
                    ...
                    }
  } 

  selectPet(e){
      this.setState({selected: e.target.value})
  }   

   render(){
       return (<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
           <input ref="name" type="text" />
           ...
           <PetsSelect onSelect={this.selectPet.bind(this)} />
         </form>)
     }
}

class PetsSelect extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props)    
   }

   render(){
     return (<select onChange={this.props.onSelect}>
                 <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
                 <option value='cat'>Cat</option>
            </select>)
   }

}
```